# 500 Internal Server Error using DeleteItem from DynamoDB using API-Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new DynamoDB table `Events` with partition key `id`
   [image: Step #1]
2. Create a new item in `Events` with an `id` of `123456`. All other fields are blank.
   [image: Step #2]
3. Create an API-Gateway. Create path of `events` and a resource of `remove-event` under it.
   [image: Step #3]
4. Create a method of `POST`. AWS Service, DynamoDB, , and an action of `DeleteItem`. Add an IAM role that has access to the `Events` table too.
   [image: Step #4]
5. Open postman. Fill out the authorization and add the following parameters:

   ```
   POST https://<DB GOES HERE>.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/prod/events/remove-event
   ```
6. In the body, put (This is following the [provided sample request here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteItem.html)):

   ```
   {
       "TableName": "Events",
       "Key": {
           "id": {
               "S": "123456"
           }
       },
       "ReturnValues": "NONE"
   }
   ```
7. Finally, hit send.

   ```
   {
       "message": "Internal server error"
   }
   ```

I have no idea what is causing this. Create, Update, and Read work with issue. It is ONLY Delete that fails.

**EDIT**: In case anyone is curious about my policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:*:<sensitive infomation>:*/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Removing this changes the `500` response to a `403`, so this is not a policy issue.

Comment: Please check APIGW role has delete permissions or not

Comment: It has the "execute-api:Invoke" Action...isn't that enough?

Comment: Just verified that removing this permission changes the response to a 403 error, so this is not a policy  ssue.